# Problem in Caching Images in ASP.Net in IIS 7

Tags: .net, asp.net, image, iis-7, caching

I have implemented caching Images in my website, It is working fine in **IIS 6** but not working in **IIS 7** problem is images not shown on my website on iis7 hosted server but shown on iss6 hosted server

I have implemented caching using this Article....
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CachingImagesInASPNET.aspx

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong or anyone have good suggestion regarding Image caching.....Any hellp will realy appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't adding far future cache expiration headers to you images dir in IIS?  This is the recommended why to add cache headers to you images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick edit to web.config for caching images/css/js in .NET

```
<staticContent>
 <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
</staticContent>
```

see this post: http://madskristensen.net/post/Add-expires-header-for-images.aspx

Comment: If you want to cache for, for example, 1 day and 4 hours, use: <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="1.04:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />

Answer (score 0):

You might need to register the handler... Is it in you web.config for IIS7?

try looking at this link?

```
<add path="*.ashx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" validate="True" />
```

[IIS7 file mappings - .asax, .ashx, .asap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702572/iis7-file-mappings-asax-ashx-asap)

Comment: add, but no success, any other findings? Thanks

Comment: just for arguments sake can you post a url that is having the problem?
I want to see what you are using exactly.

Comment: I have changed IIS pipeline mode integrated to classic, images are shown, Problem seems to be resolved, but when setting pipeline mode to integrated, issue still remain,,. setting classic identical to IIS 6.. any thought.... Thanks

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx

Comment: Sorry I am out of ideas... Try Posting A question to the CodeProject forum for that solution... I will continue to think about it..   I have a file handler doing something similar on my IIS7 machine... and its working.. so it has to be some kind of setup/config issue :(