# How can I know under which IIS version my Asp.Net application is running?

Tags: .net, asp.net, frameworks

How can I know under which IIS version my web application is running in development server?

As .Net framework 2.0,3.0,3.5,4.0 have support built in IIS....

Thanks

Comment: I am curious as to why you need to know the IIS version.

Comment: Why would you like to find out what version of IIS in particular is running?  If your web application is infact running, then it must already meet certain pre-requisites, such as IIS being installed, otherwise the code wouldn't be running.

Comment: @DoctaJones: .Net framework above 1.1 do not required IIS, .net framework 2.0,3.0,3.5 have support built in IIS

Comment: @tomfanning: I have Window Vista, In my machine IIS 6 and IIS 7 is installed, When I deploying website its working perfectly on IIS 6 hosted server and but not on IIS 6 hosted server. plz check this my post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068153/problem-in-caching-images-in-asp-net-in-iis-7

Comment: @tomfanning/@DoctaJonez: To support both you might need some code changes (e.g. how wildcard handlers operate with ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: why this post become as community, I don't know who have update this and why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the IIS version of the webserver you can use the SERVER_SOFTWARE [server variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525396.aspx).

```
Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
```

It will return something like as follows:

Microsoft-IIS/5.0 (Windows 2000)

Microsoft-IIS/5.1 (Windows XP)

Microsoft-IIS/6.0 (Windows 2003 Server)

You can find a full reference of server variables [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

This is available directly from the `SERVER_SOFTWARE` server variable:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
```

which is a string like "`Microsoft-IIS/7.0`".

NB, the string is empty for the ASP.NET development server ("Casini").

Comment: Using the development server => not using IIS, so the question does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

> @AnthonyWJones "So the question
>   becomes, How does an ASP.NET
>   application determine what operating
>   system it is running on?"

You can use [System.Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**The version number can be queried from the Windows Registry:**

On windows, run regedit and navigate to this directory:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\VersionString
```

Mine returns Version 6.0 because I am running Windows 2003 Server.

Answer (score 0):

I saw someone already answered to a degree, but I did want to mention that the best practice is to include your .NET target environment into your ASP.NET application. This way the target environment will be present.